# Weak topology generated by family of functions is weakest wrt which each of the given functions is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\mathcal{F}=\{ f_\alpha:X \rightarrow X_\alpha, \alpha \in A\}$ be a family of functions from X onto topological spaces $X_\alpha$. The weak topology for X generated by functions $f_\alpha$ is the topology determined by the subbasis of open sets $\{ f^{-1}_\alpha (O_\alpha): \alpha \in \mathcal{A}, O_\alpha$ open in $X_\alpha\}$.

Why would the weak topology defined above be the weakest topology with respect to each of which of the given function is continuous?

Suppose we have a family of constant functions (they are continuous), then the topology generated is just the trivial topology, wouldn't it in this case be weaker than the weak topology also?

Comment: Your example shows only that the weakest topology where constant functions are continuous is the trivial topology (which is the weakest topology possible), so what's your question about this example?

Comment: We don't compare topologies for different sets of functions. We fix a set of functions and then compare different topologies where these functions are continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want our functions $f_\alpha$ to be continuous, then the preimage of any open set has to be open (by definition), therefore, all the sets $f^{-1}(O_\alpha)$ have to be open.

On the other hand, this family of sets satisfies the definition of being the basis of a topology (should be quite easy to verify).

Therefore, this topology in minimal (i.e. the weakest) among topologies which make the functions $f_\alpha$ continuous - it simply has nothing but necessary sets for continuity.

Comment: I am still confused, couldn't the weak topology generated by the constant functions be weaker than the weak topology generated by any arbitrary continuous functions?

Comment: @user90831 We don't compare topologies for different sets of functions. We fix a set of functions and then compare different topologies where these functions are continuous.

Comment: Ah I got it now! Thanks for clearing the doubts.

Comment: Hi, I just need one final clarification, how is it possible (Is there an example) where we have a family of functions fixed, and some of these functions are continuous and others are not? In the case of family constant functions, all of them are continuous.

Comment: Let for simplicity $X=\Bbb R$, $X_{1,2}=\Bbb R$. $\forall x\,f_1(x)=0$ and $f_2(x)=sgn(x)$. If we equip $X$ with trivial topology and $X_i$ with standard topology, then $f_1$ is continuous and $f_2$ is not.

Comment: Regarding your second statement, I don't think this family need be a basis in general. The product topology $\prod_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}} X_\alpha$ can be phrased in this form with the projection maps, and $\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}(O_\alpha) : O_\alpha \subset X_\alpha \text{ open }, \alpha \in \mathcal{A} \}$ is usually not a basis.

Comment: @jet457 It's been quite a while since I touched these subjects, so I can not give an answer right now. When I have time to check your statement, I'll get back to you =). I upvoted your comment for visibility.

Comment: @Tzakrevskiy I submitted an edit to your response. The main content of your answer is not really affected by this.